# can't communicate between classes using delegations

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have model class which has color parameter, and view class which also has UIColor. Using delegations how can I change my view color, when it changes in model.

```
//Model.h

@class Ball;
@protocol BallDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)ball:(Ball*)ball wasColorChanged;

@end

@interface Ball : NSObject

@property UIColor* color;
@property (weak) id <BallDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Now, how can I pass the value to my view, how to invoke that.

Comment: You need a `setColor` method in your `Ball` class that invokes the delegate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **model.m**

```
[self.delegate wasColorChanged]   // call this at the time of color change
```

And in ViewController or wherever you can to receive the event,

In **ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()<BallDelegate>  // Set ballDelegate in interface
```

set the delegate where you create your object

```
myBallModel.delegate = self;   // set it where you created your object
```

and add the delegate function in **viewController.m**

```
-(void)ball:(Ball*)ball wasColorChanged {
   // You will receive the color change event here
}
```

Comment: Finally I understood delegation using (maybe :D ). But there is one question still. The thing is I have a BallManager singleton class and only there new balls are created. so if I set there new balls delegate how can I set it as my viewcontroller? :/